# Easy-webpack using additional loaders

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I have a easy-webpack configuration (default one from Aurelia).

We have a library (autobahn) that we use, that tries to load a package.json.
When that happens, it errors out.

```
./~/autobahn/package.json
Module parse failed: /media/aurelia_app/node_modules/    autobahn/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "_args": [
|     [
|       {
 @ ./~/autobahn/lib/autobahn.js 17:12-38
 @ ./~/autobahn/index.js
 @ ./src ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./~/aurelia-loader-webpack/dist/commonjs/aurelia-loader-webpack.js
 @ multi aurelia
```

In order to make it work, we have to add a additionalLoader for json.

Here is our config file

```
"use strict";

/**
 * To learn more about how to use Easy Webpack
 * Take a look at the README here: https://github.com/easy-webpack/core
 **/
const easyWebpack = require('@easy-webpack/core');
const generateConfig = easyWebpack.default;
const get = easyWebpack.get;
const path = require('path');
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() || 'development';
let config;

// basic configuration:
const title = 'Overpass Business App';
const baseUrl = '/';
const rootDir = path.resolve();
const srcDir = path.resolve('src');
const outDir = path.resolve('dist');

const coreBundles = {
  bootstrap: [
    'aurelia-bootstrapper-webpack',
    'aurelia-polyfills',
    'aurelia-pal',
    'aurelia-pal-browser',
    'regenerator-runtime',
    'bluebird'
  ],
  // these will be included in the 'aurelia' bundle (except for the above bootstrap packages)
  aurelia: [
    'aurelia-bootstrapper-webpack',
    'aurelia-binding',
    'aurelia-dependency-injection',
    'aurelia-event-aggregator',
    'aurelia-framework',
    'aurelia-history',
    'aurelia-history-browser',
    'aurelia-loader',
    'aurelia-loader-webpack',
    'aurelia-logging',
    'aurelia-logging-console',
    'aurelia-metadata',
    'aurelia-pal',
    'aurelia-pal-browser',
    'aurelia-path',
    'aurelia-polyfills',
    'aurelia-route-recognizer',
    'aurelia-router',
    'aurelia-task-queue',
    'aurelia-templating',
    'aurelia-templating-binding',
    'aurelia-templating-router',
    'aurelia-templating-resources'
  ]
}

const baseConfig = {
  entry: {
    'app': [/* this is filled by the aurelia-webpack-plugin */],
    'aurelia-bootstrap': coreBundles.bootstrap,
    'aurelia': coreBundles.aurelia.filter(pkg => coreBundles.bootstrap.indexOf(pkg) === -1)
  },
  output: {
    path: outDir,
  }
}

// advanced configuration:
switch (ENV) {
  case 'production':
    config = generateConfig(
      baseConfig,

      require('@easy-webpack/config-env-production')
        ({compress: true}),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-aurelia')
        ({root: rootDir, src: srcDir, title: title, baseUrl: baseUrl}),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-babel')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-html')(),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-css')
        ({ filename: 'styles.css', allChunks: true, sourceMap: false }),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-fonts-and-images')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-global-bluebird')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-global-jquery')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-global-regenerator')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-generate-index-html')
        ({minify: true}),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-copy-files')
        ({patterns: [{ from: 'favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' }]}),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-common-chunks-simple')
        ({appChunkName: 'app', firstChunk: 'aurelia-bootstrap'}),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-uglify')
        ({debug: false})
    );
    break;

  case 'test':
    config = generateConfig(
      baseConfig,

      require('@easy-webpack/config-env-development')
        ({devtool: 'inline-source-map'}),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-aurelia')
        ({root: rootDir, src: srcDir, title: title, baseUrl: baseUrl}),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-babel')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-html')(),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-css')
        ({ filename: 'styles.css', allChunks: true, sourceMap: false }),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-fonts-and-images')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-global-bluebird')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-global-jquery')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-global-regenerator')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-generate-index-html')(),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-test-coverage-istanbul')()
    );
    break;

  default:
  case 'development':
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
    config = generateConfig(
      baseConfig,

      require('@easy-webpack/config-env-development')(),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-aurelia')
        ({root: rootDir, src: srcDir, title: title, baseUrl: baseUrl}),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-babel')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-html')(),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-css')
        ({ filename: 'styles.css', allChunks: true, sourceMap: false }),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-fonts-and-images')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-global-bluebird')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-global-jquery')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-global-regenerator')(),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-generate-index-html')
        ({minify: false}),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-copy-files')
        ({patterns: [{ from: 'favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' }]}),

      require('@easy-webpack/config-common-chunks-simple')
        ({appChunkName: 'app', firstChunk: 'aurelia-bootstrap'})
    );
    break;
}

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add module for the loaders in the base config.

```
const baseConfig = {
  entry: {
    'app': [/* this is filled by the aurelia-webpack-plugin */],
    'aurelia-bootstrap': coreBundles.bootstrap,
    'aurelia': coreBundles.aurelia.filter(pkg =>     coreBundles.bootstrap.indexOf(pkg) === -1)
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
    ]
   },

  output: {
    path: outDir,
  }
}
```